# Inserting element on numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

```
path = glob.glob('Foto/*.jpg')
x = 0
for i in path:
    
    matrix = cv2.imread(i)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(matrix, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_mat = np.array([np.array(gray)]).astype(float)
    
    

print(img_mat.shape)
```

I have about 50 files in 'Foto/' Folder with the resolution of 100x120, so the img_mat.shape should be (50, 100, 120) but why is it only showing (1, 100, 120)??

ps. sorry if my english is bad

Comment: When you write a loop like that an just set a variable to something, does it accumulate anything?  Why should it be (50,...)?  You haven't done anything to "insert" or "add" `gray` to any preexisting array.  Practice adding something, list or array to a list in a loop.

Comment: `np.array([np.array(gray)]).astype(float)`, or just `np.array([gray], dtype=float)` makes one (1,100,120) shaped array.  `img_mat = ...` just assigns that to the `img_mat` variable, replacing anything that was previously assigned to it.